# Is it possible to create a view in postgresql that returns random values for any column?

Tags: postgresql

Specifically, for a query like "select hoge, fuga, piyo from random_view," can a view named "random_view" be defined that returns random values for each column without having previously created the columns "hoge," "fuga," and "piyo"? Other methods besides views are also fine. The database being used is postgresql.

Comment: You cannot do this with a view or a table - they have a defined "shape" so the columns and types are known beforehand. You might be able to do it with a custom function and specifying the row-type you expect to be returned but you are going to have to define custom random-data generators for each type of data you want returned.

Comment: I have come to realize that the feature I desire may not be easily achievable. Thank you.